# Does the "Khaine's Fury" Chaos Wastes boon also activate on temporary health?

Tags: warhammer-vermintide-2

[image]

The Chaos Wastes game mode boon, "Khaine's Fury" is described:

> While above 50% health, you gain 25% more melee power but deal 3 damage to yourself every swing.

By "health" does this also mean temp (white) health, aside from the permanent (green) health? I'm wondering if I need to heal my permanent health, or if I can make do with temp health to activate this boon.